# Global styles for specific pages in next js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, next.js

In my NextJS app, I have a `/home` page in which I need x and y overflow to be hidden. However, I have another `/books` page in which I need the user to be able to scroll. However, as there is only one global stylesheet in Next and global css selectors like `body` are not allowed in css modules, I could not find a way to get around this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Done! Just insert the following into the component:

```
<style global jsx>{`
        html,
        body {
          overflow: hidden;
        }
`}</style>
```

Comment: Note: This can be provided inside Head component from next/head. Good solution!

Comment: @Gogol Adding it inside `Head` stopped it from working for me. I had to remove `Head` and make `<style global jsx>` a child of `<>`. Any idea why? I'm a Next noob.

Comment: @EricEskildsen just do something like `https://pastebin.com/Rbe9ebvm`. Tried just now and it works perfectly fine. :)

Comment: @Gogol Works great. (For future readers in case of link rot, Gogol's sample code uses `<style>` inside `<Head>` instead of `<style global jsx>`.) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Just embed `<style>{'body { overflow: auto; }'}</style>` in your component:

```
export default function MyPage({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <style>{'body { overflow: auto; }'}</style>
      <div>
        something...
        {children}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: for me thekey part of this answer is to wrap it in a `fragment`. For me if the `<style>` jsx component is wrapped in a `div`, the styles weren't applied.

Answer (score 0):

You already gave the general right answer how to add global stylesheets from specific page or component. However, for this specific case of hiding scrollbar in React application, I can suggest to take a look at `useLockBodyScroll` from package `react-use`.

https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLockBodyScroll.md